# Entity Framework code first: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Players' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to perform a simple upsert by using Entity Framework and code first. But no matter what I try to do, I get this error message:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Players'
> when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Despite the fact that this is a relatively common error message, I cannot find out why this fails in my case. I do not set the Id explicitly anywhere, but I can see that it has a 0 value when I'm inspecting the player object.

I'm getting the error on context.SaveChanges(); here:

```
using (var context = new FantasyEliteserienContext())
        {
            foreach (var element in bootstrap.elements)
            {
                var player = Mapping.MapElementToPlayer(element);

                context.Players.AddOrUpdate(player);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

The Player class/model looks like this (I have removed a lot of regular properties for readability):

```
public class Player
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int player_id { get; set; }
    public int? code { get; set; }
    public int cost_change_event { get; set; }
}
```

The context-class looks like this:

```
public class FantasyEliteserienContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone see what the problem is? I understand that I can't explicitly set the values for the identity column here, but I don't understand why it is happening.

Comment: What is `player_id` for?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: player_id is an id used by the external part where I get the data from.

To create the MRE requested I decided to just start the project from scratch, and now it is working. Hard to say what has happened here, but something have probably gone wrong one of the many times I have changed the configuration, created and rolled back on migrations or something else as I was learning EF with code first.

Regardless, thank you for the response.